# Interprocess communication on local machine on Windows using COM

Tags: c++, windows, com, inter-process-communicat

I was investigating the option of doing **interprocess communication on Windows using COM and C++**.

I found [this article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), offering a list of interprocess communication options for Windows, and COM is one of them.
But, unfortunately, the COM option is just listed without much details.

Does someone have any pointers about doc or other resources on how to use COM for interprocess communication on Windows?

I'm not interested in communicating with remote machines (so: *no DCOM*); I'm just interested in interprocess communication on the same local machine.

The idea would be to define some custom COM interfaces implementing some custom communication protocol, and then have a server program and a client program (each one in its own process, running on the same local machine), and use COM to communicate between the two (e.g. the client makes requests to the server, and the server returns proper answers, everything using COM interfaces).

So, for example: are there predefined COM interfaces to implement an interprocess communication? If so, what are them?

It would be helpful to have some tutorial or a more detailed guide about this subject.

Comment: Supporting process interop is an innate ability in COM, it doesn't require "special" interfaces.  We don't do tutorial links here, but you already know that.

Comment: I have knowledge of _in-proc_ COM DLLs (e.g. shell extensions), but I've never done an out-of-proc COM server, neither I've ever used COM as a form of inteprocess communication. @patthoyts's answer is at least an initial guidance mentioning this _"Running Object Table"_ element. COM is huge and having some pointers to focused documentation and tutorial is really helpful.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a COM interface that both sides know about then one process can register some object implementing that with the [Running Object Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms695276(v=vs.85).aspx) using a moniker. The other process can then retrieve the object from this interprocess table using the moniker identifier and query it for the known interface. Now the client process has a reference to something existing in the other process and calls will be marshalled by COM.

There are lots of things to go wrong though, particularly with ensuring your interfaces are being marshalled correctly. Marshalling is often not well tested until you start using multiple processes or you have been using .Net with your COM interfaces. Using [oleautomation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367129%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) compatible types and marking the interface in IDL with the `[oleautomation]` attribute can help to ensure typelibrary marshalling will work but also attention to the other attributes used with arrays is important. We found this with the [IPropertyBag2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768194(v=vs.85).aspx) interface some years ago. The Visual Studio 6 IDL description looks like this in ocidl.idl:

```
HRESULT Read(
            [in] ULONG cProperties,
            [in] PROPBAG2 * pPropBag,
            [in] IErrorLog * pErrLog,
            [out] VARIANT * pvarValue,
            [out] HRESULT * phrError
        );
```

and does not marshall more than a single VARIANT from the array provided. The newer version looks like this:

```
HRESULT Read(
           [in] ULONG cProperties,
           [in, size_is(cProperties)] PROPBAG2 * pPropBag,
           [in, unique] IErrorLog * pErrLog,
           [out, size_is(cProperties)] VARIANT * pvarValue,
           [in, out, unique, size_is(cProperties)] HRESULT * phrError
       );
```

which correctly associates the size of the `pvarValue` array with the size specified by the `cProperties` parameter. Assuming a typelibrary with the second definition has been registered then this interface should marshal properly now but a few years ago those missing parameters cost us a few brain cells working out why persistence was failing.

Comment: Thanks for these pointers to the Running Object Table and for other general information. Could you please elaborate a little bit about the interface marshaling going wrong? I mean: sure I would not have STL classes like `std::vector` at the interface boundaries, but would I be safe if I restrict the types at the marshalled interfaces to "simple" types like integers, booleans, and COM types like `BSTR` and other interface pointers (e.g. `IUnknown*`)?

Comment: I expanded on some marshalling pitfalls encountered in the past.

Comment: Let me just warn you that the second definition is worth nothing in terms of type libraries, as they don't describe array parameter's length.  For automation arrays, you must use `SAFEARRAY` or a `VARIANT` pointing to one.  The second definition will work if you use midl.exe to generate proxy-stub code to include in a DLL (the component's DLL or a separate DLL) and to be registered for the interface in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Interface`.

Comment: Indeed, checking with oleview the IPropertyBag2 interface uses a custom class provided by oleaut32 and is not using type library marshalling.

Comment: Thanks both @PauloMadeira and patthoyts for your additional comments with details. Do you guys have some links to tutorials or other documentation I can read to better understand this application of COM to interprocess communication? Thanks. FWIW, I found a [7-step tutorial on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/675/DCOM-D-Mystified-A-DCOM-Tutorial-Step), but I think it's probably too much for my needs, since I'm only interested in processes running on the same local machine. Although some interfaces like `IConnectionPoint` etc. discussed there may be applied to my case, too...

Comment: That's what you should do up to step 6, if you're using ATL, or willing to, and that you already have an application.  Since you're not interested in remote machine access, you can 1) register the server with `LocalServer32` and make it call `CoRegisterClassObject`, and call `CoCreateInstance` on the client, or 2) call `RegisterActiveObject` on the server and call `GetActiveObject` on the client, or 3) use the running object table directly (see `GetRunningObjectTable`), or 4) implement `WM_GETOBJECT` on the server and call `AccessibleObjectFromWindow` on the client with `OBJID_NATIVEOM`...

Comment: And none of these options are exclusive.  If you just want to see something up and running, go with 1, if you need a singleton, go with 2 or 3 (not script friendly) and you'll have to make sure the application is running by other means (i.e. do your own activation).  Option 4 could be useful if you have a way to pick a window, much like Spy++, Process Explorer or Fiddler (⊕).